# How do I make two arrays in which first one would be values and second one would be keys for those values?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am creating two arrays.
First one contains images, second one contains equal amount of numbers.
How do I make second array of integers correspond to first array, so I would have a specific integer value for each picture?

Comment: You're essentially describing a dictionary, why not use that instead?

Comment: I need to use arrays only without dictionary for this project.

Comment: Does the order of the images matter?

Comment: If you cannot use a dictionary can you use an array of two-element structures, or are structures disallowed as well?

Comment: well i am using a deck of 52 cards, therefore it would matter to later on calculate scores for players

Comment: structures are disallowed as well.

Comment: This sounds like a quiz question ;-) Can you declare your own type (presumably a class if structures are disallowed) which has your two arrays as instance variables?

Comment: I could, but since i'm just learning, how can I do that? :)

Comment: what does the integer represent? the card's position, an identifier, a pointer?

Comment: I suppose if you create a hard-coded convention in your app, to label each card from 0-51, and have it set up so that: spades are in order 0-12, clubs 13-25, and so on, you could technically represent the array of images (which really, are the cards). So that if you parse through the given integer-only array, in any order, then the resulting value could technically be extrapolated, associated to a string (the name of the card image in your bundle), and then returned. I'll post a little example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i said in my comment. You could apply a convention, then use an extension on `Int` to return the image the number describes:

```
let arrInt = [0, 1, 2, 3] //any number of integers

let cardnames = ["AceOfSpades", "OneOfSpades", "TwoOfSpades"] //etc...


extension Int {
    var cardName : UIImage? {
        guard self <= 51 else { return nil } //because any number greater than this would not represent a card in your 53-card deck
        return UIImage(named: cardNames[self])
    }
}
```

You would essentially use it as:

```
func AllImagesInTheDeck() -> [UIImage] {
    var images : [UIImage] = []
    for integer in arrInt {
        if let image = integer.cardName {
            images.append(image)
        }
    }
    return images
}
```

From then on, you can manipulate the arrInt itself, of individual integer arrays for each player, and to return their card images, you could either call the AllImages method (which shouldn't be a hard hit on performance since array length shouldn't be too long for this case. Or, you can directly manipulate the integer arrays from there on out, and add more methods to determine which new card images are added, etc. This is while if any struct or class must be avoided, otherwise if you can, incorporating this approach with CRD's class example would work well too.

Comment: oops, thanks for the heads up on the typo and misreading his value lol........................ ;)

Answer (score 0):

After the comments you could start with:

```
class PairedArrays
{
   // instance variables - arrays for the images and values, start of empty
   var images : [NSImage] = []
   var values : [Int] = []

   // add a new image/value pair
   func addPair(image : NSImage, values : Int) -> Void { ... }

   // retrieve integer associated with image
   func getAssociatedInt(key : NSImage) -> Int { ... }
}
```

Now you need to:

- Read up on classes in Swift
- Fill in the ...
- Make it generic so it works with types other than images and integers (optional, but useful knowledge)
- Having used it as a learning tool try using an array of `struct` which will *guarantee* images & values are always added in pairs (think `struct PlayingCard { ... }`)
- Now try it with a dictionary
- Compare the last two and decide which suits your application model the best

HTH